# Formula for the partial sum of a geometric series when ratio equals one

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

I'm searching for a *numerical implementation* of a formula of $S_N$, the partial sum of a geometric series (i.e. the sum of the $N<\infty$ first terms of a geometric sequence, starting at $n=0$) with a ratio $r$ which can be equal to 1. Definion of $S_N$:

$$S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n$$

The classical closed-formed formula is:

$$S_N = \frac{1-r^N}{1-r}$$

which is not defined for $r=1$. However, from the definition (or, with a bit more work, from the closed-form formula) we have $S_N \to N$ when $r\to 1$ while the closed-formed formula is ill-defined (0/0) when $r\to 1$.

My question is: is there an alternative formula which is  well-defined for $r\to 1$?

A bit of context (from finance): I'm in fact interesting in computing the [Capital recovery factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_recovery_factor) when the interest rate $i$ can be 0. This is related to the above problem with $CRF = 1/(r.S_N)$ and $r = 1/(1+i)$. I want to avoid an implementation with subcases (`if` $i>0$ ... `else` ...).

Comment: Why not just write out the terms when $r=1$ and see what you notice ...

Comment: When $r=1$, all terms are $1$, so $S_N = N$.

Comment: You might also notice a connection with l'hôpital's rule for limits (which is overkill here)

Comment: As mentioned, my question is not about proving that the closed-formed formula converge to $N$, but about having a *formula which has a good numerical behavior* close to $r=1$

Comment: To emphasize how this question is grounded in the use of computer algorithms rather than pure math, I suggest the tag numerical-computing. In addition, since the problem is really catastrophic cancellation near zero, the tag catastrophic-cancellation would be appropriate, though it seems to be underused on this site.

Comment: In the problem where the input is a number $i$ and $r = 1/(1+i),$ for very small non-zero $i$, using IEEE-754 arithmetic there are losses due to limited precision in a number of places in the classic formula, including the calculation of $r$ itself. The fact that the formula is undefined when $r = 1$ exactly does not say much about the problem you are actually trying to solve. If the concern is about values of $i$ that are **not** zero but are very small, such as $i = 10^{-17}$, then please say so in the text of the question.

Comment: Once I thought about your own answer to this question, I realized the question is much more interesting than I initially thought. I may have spent more time than I should have writing additional parts of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We know $S_N=N$ from the definition (the sequence is $1,1,\dots,1$), but you seem to know this already.

The closed form formula *does* have the correct limit: with L'Hopital's Rule,

$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow 1} \left[\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}\right] = \lim_{r\rightarrow 1} \left[\frac{-Nr^{N-1}}{-1}\right] = \lim_{r\rightarrow 1} \left[Nr^{N-1}\right] = N $$

You also seem to know this.

I think the fundamental question is how you could possibly need "to avoid an implementation with subcases". Whether in a functional or imperative programming language, it should be simple to calculate the formula differently for $i=0$ in a way that only the calculation is done separately and no other code is duplicated.

The only formula that I am aware of that finds the sum of a geometric series and works for $r=1$ is $S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n$.

Comment: About my interest to avoid special cases, it's more a concern about having a "jump" at the boundary, especially if one formula behaves numerically bad close to the case boundary.

Comment: In my [proposed answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304301/289775), I've found a formula which behaves well with $r$ *close to* $1$. However, I failed to find one also working for $r=1$, so it's an open question whether such a formula exist or not. Still, since my proposed formula works for $r=1-10^{-17}$, I have not much interest in searching further...

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** There are two parts to this answer. First, the part I wrote originally when focused on the complaint that the classic formula "is ill-defined ($0/0$) when $r\to 1$."

---

Technically, your problem is not with $r \to 1$ (which is a limit notation),
it's when $r = 1$ exactly.

A formula that always works, mathematically speaking, is

$$ S_N(r) = \lim_{\theta \to r} \frac{1-\theta^N}{1-\theta}. $$

To actually implement this in software, however, you would have to implement the evaluation of the limit, which is almost certainly going to be much more expensive than an "if" statement (both in effort to code it and in processing time).

Perhaps it's possible to derive a simpler formula that is good for all $r$,
but my general experience is that when there are one or two special cases where the "general" method doesn't work, it makes much more sense in every way to just code the special cases separately.

But if you want your code to be as bullet-proof as possible, don't write
"if $i>0$" in your code;
put the check in the function that computes $S_N$ (which presumably has input parameters $r$ and $N$). The code there would start with "if $r \neq 1$".

---

The second part of this answer concerns the inaccuracies in the classic formula when it is used in a typical fixed-precision floating-point computer algorithm for values of $r$ that are less than $1$ but very close to $1$,
as illustrated in
[the self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304301/139123).
That is, we now look at small positive values of $\varepsilon$,
where $\varepsilon = 1 - r$.

The first question is, what kind of function are we investigating?
Is it a function that takes $r$ and $N$ and evaluates a geometric series of $N$ terms with ratio $r$,
or is it a function that takes $\varepsilon$ and $N$ and evaluates a geometric series of $N$ terms with ratio $1 - \varepsilon$?

This choice affects the kind of accuracy we can get from the function.
When $r$ is slightly less than $1$ and is stored as an IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating-point number, the unit of least precision (ulp)
is $2^{-53} \approx 1.11 \times 10^{-16}.$
So if one of the inputs to the function is $r,$ we have the ability to specify that $\varepsilon = 0,$ we can specify that $\varepsilon = 2^{-53},$
we can specify that $\varepsilon = 2^{-52},$ and
we can specify that $\varepsilon = 3\times 2^{-53},$
but we have no way to specify that $\varepsilon$ is between any two consecutive numbers in that list.

The "zero div. error" in
[the self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304301/139123)
is due to this limited ability for values of $r$ to distinguish different values of $\varepsilon$.
As soon as $\varepsilon \leq 2^{-54} \approx 5.55\times 10^{-17}$, the representation of $r$ is $1$ exactly, $1 - r$ evaluates to $0$ exactly, and the divide-by-zero error occurs.
Hence the only thing you need to do to protect against that error is to test for $r = 1$ (or equivalently $1 - \varepsilon = 1$).

Moreover, if all you need is an answer accurate to seven or eight significant digits, rounded, we can from the results that the classic algorithm is fine even for very small $\epsilon$ when $N=100,$ provided that you handle the $r=1$ case by returning $N.$
The same behavior persists for larger values of $N$; even for $N=10^9$ the results of the classic formula are correct when rounded to seven digits.

Where the classic formula does not do so well is if you are looking for much more than seven or eight digits of accuracy, as seen in the following table for $N=100,$ covering a sequence of $\varepsilon$ values from $2^{-34}$ to $2^{-32}.$
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
  \varepsilon \qquad &   r \qquad &   \text{Classical formula}\quad & \Delta \qquad &  \text{Taylor $3$ terms}\quad &  \Delta \qquad\\
 5.821\mathrm e{-}11 & 0.999999999941792 & 100.000000000000000 &          ---  & 99.999999711872078 &          --- \\
 7.276\mathrm e{-}11 & 0.999999999927240 & 100.000000000000000 &            0  & 99.999999639840098 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 8.731\mathrm e{-}11 & 0.999999999912689 & 100.000000000000000 &            0  & 99.999999567808118 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 1.019\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999898137 & 100.000000000000000 &            0  & 99.999999495776137 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 1.164\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999883585 &  99.999999046325684 &  -9.5367\mathrm e{-}7 & 99.999999423744157 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 1.310\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999869033 &  99.999999152289490 &   1.0596\mathrm e{-}7 & 99.999999351712177 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 1.455\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999854481 &  99.999999237060550 &   8.4771\mathrm e{-}8 & 99.999999279680196 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 1.601\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999839929 &  99.999999306418673 &   6.9358\mathrm e{-}8 & 99.999999207648216 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 1.746\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999825377 &  99.999999364217118 &   5.7798\mathrm e{-}8 & 99.999999135616235 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 1.892\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999810825 &  99.999998826246994 &  -5.3797\mathrm e{-}7 & 99.999999063584255 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 2.037\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999796273 &  99.999998910086489 &   8.3839\mathrm e{-}8 & 99.999998991552275 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 2.183\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999781721 &  99.999998982747400 &   7.2661\mathrm e{-}8 & 99.999998919520309 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
 2.328\mathrm e{-}10 & 0.999999999767169 &  99.999999046325684 &   6.3578\mathrm e{-}8 & 99.999998847488328 &  -7.2032\mathrm e{-}8 \\
\end{array}

Again, the data in the "classic formula" column are correct when rounded to seven significant digits, but the last several digits are obviously erratic.
The figures under "Taylor $3$ terms" were generated by the Python formula

```
N - (N*(N-1)*eps/2 - N*(N-1)*(N-2)*eps*eps/6)
```

which is simply the first three terms of the Taylor series of the classic formula (rearranged to combine the smaller terms first).
This is the formula I trust the best for $N=100$ and
$0 < \varepsilon < 10^{-9}$
(and possibly somewhat larger); mathematically, its error is guaranteed to be less than the fourth term of the Taylor series, which would be much smaller than one ulp, and I do not think we give up much in the few operations performed here. (I have also tried several rearrangements of the sequence of operations, but I got the same results ever time.)

The reason has much to do with catastrophic cancellation in the numerator of the classic formula. (The denominator is not a problem in these particular examples since the values of $\varepsilon$ are nice round numbers in binary floating-point representation.)

The approximation $N\left(1-\frac{N-1}{2}\varepsilon\right),$ that is, two terms of the Taylor expansion instead of three, seems to be good for
$0 < \varepsilon < 2.04\times10^{-10},$ that is, for most of the rows of the table above and for smaller positive values of $\varepsilon.$

The formula `-expm1(N*log1p(-eps))/eps` also performs well, as shown in the table below.
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
         \varepsilon & \text{Formula with expm1} &   \text{diff} & \text{Taylor $3$ terms} \\
 5.821\mathrm e{-}11 &     99.999999711872078 &                     0 & 99.999999711872078 \\
 7.276\mathrm e{-}11 &     99.999999639840098 &                     0 & 99.999999639840098 \\
 8.731\mathrm e{-}11 &     99.999999567808118 &                     0 & 99.999999567808118 \\
 1.019\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999999495776137 &                     0 & 99.999999495776137 \\
 1.164\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999999423744157 &                     0 & 99.999999423744157 \\
  1.31\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999999351712177 &                     0 & 99.999999351712177 \\
 1.455\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999999279680196 &                     0 & 99.999999279680196 \\
 1.601\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999999207648216 &                     0 & 99.999999207648216 \\
 1.746\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999999135616235 &                     0 & 99.999999135616235 \\
 1.892\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999999063584255 &                     0 & 99.999999063584255 \\
 2.037\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999998991552289 & -1.4211\mathrm e{-}14 & 99.999998991552275 \\
 2.183\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999998919520294 &  1.4211\mathrm e{-}14 & 99.999998919520309 \\
 2.328\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999998847488314 &  1.4211\mathrm e{-}14 & 99.999998847488328 \\
 2.474\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999998775456348 &                     0 & 99.999998775456348 \\
 2.619\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999998703424367 &                     0 & 99.999998703424367 \\
 2.765\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999998631392387 &                     0 & 99.999998631392387 \\
  2.91\mathrm e{-}10 &     99.999998559360407 &                     0 & 99.999998559360407 \\
\end{array}

The column headed "diff" shows the differences between the two results, which are never more than $\pm 1$ ulp apart.
The `expm1` formula is just a little irregular in a couple of places, for example in one step in which it decreases by two ulps more than in the step before. I trust the Taylor series better in this range but $\pm 1$ ulp from this is quite good.

If we really want a general-purpose summation formula for a finite geometric series with ratio $1 - \varepsilon$, however, it really ought to work well for all values of input that do not cause overflow, not just for tiny $\varepsilon$. For example, for $N=32$ and $\varepsilon=-1,$ an exact result is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (1 - \varepsilon)^n = 4294967295.
$$
The classic formula delivers this result exactly in python, but the formula with `expm1` returns $4294967294.9999967$; this is accurate when rounded to fifteen digits, but it differs from the exact result by considerably more than just one ulp.

Now consider the case $r = 0,$ or $\varepsilon = 1.$
In this case the sum is $1$ for any $N,$ which the classic formula returns exactly. But `log1p` throws `ValueError: math domain error`.
In fact, `log1p` will throw this same exception whenever
$\varepsilon \geq 1,$ with the result that we cannot evaluate any alternating sums.

So while I think the `expm1` formula performs well on a suitable part of the domain, use of that formula **requires** an "if else" in order to deal with the large part of the natural domain of the summation on which the `expm1` formula cannot be used.
There is nothing wrong with this; on the contrary, as I've been saying, an compulsive avoidance of "if else" code is worse.

---

I think, however, that all of this so far, including the
[the self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304301/139123),
does not really address the context of the original question, which was the evaluation of
$$
f(i, N) =
 \frac{1}{\frac{1}{1+i} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \left(\frac{1}{1+i}\right)^n}.
$$
Here $\frac{1}{1+i}$ is *approximately* $1 - i$ when $i$ is very small, but how good is the approximation, and what do we do when $i$ is not quite small enough? If we are really chasing after the last few ulps in every calculation, I think we need to work this problem out exactly before making an approximation. We can start by applying the classic formula:
\begin{align}
f(i, N) &= \frac{1 - \frac{1}{1+i}}
            {\frac{1}{1+i} \left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{1+i}\right)^n \right)}\\
&= \frac{i}{1 - \left(\frac{1}{1+i}\right)^n}\\
&= \frac{i (1+i)^n}{(1+i)^n - 1}\\
&= i\left(1 + \frac{1}{(1+i)^n - 1} \right).
\end{align}
Now applying some way of avoiding catastrophic cancellation in $(1+i)^n - 1$
(a formula with `expm1` and `log1p`, Taylor series, or something else,
suitably selected by an if-else, also with a special case for $i=0$)
might be enough to give good results.

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear on the fact I'm using a scientific computing software (Python, Julia...) and not a Symbolic computing engine. So, as you indeed suspected, evaluating the limit is not an option.

Comment: About my interest to avoid special cases, it's more a concern about having a "jump" at the boundary, especially if one formula behaves numerically bad close to the case boundary.

Comment: When I said "implement the evaluation of the limit" I did not assume you had a symbolic computing engine. Hence you would in effect be writing your own symbolic solver, which is why I said it would be "much more expensive ... in effort to code." (OK, I was making an understatement there.)

Comment: Note that a legitimate concern for bad numerical behavior in certain regions of the domain does not forbid if-else coding or "special cases." You might have to evaluate a function $f(x)$ for which you have two efficient methods A and B to compute it; method A is very bad near $x=0$ and good everywhere else, and method B is very bad near $x=1$ and good everywhere else. So you set up your cases so that there is an interval around $x=0$ where method $B$ is used and an interval around $x=1$ where method A is used, and elsewhere you use whichever method you think is better.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, my question is about a having a *formula which yields a good numerical implementation*. As of now, I've not found a formula which works for *all* values or $r$ (including 1), but one that behaves much better when $r \to 1$. It is based on:

1. using the definition of power via the exponential and logarithm functions
2. using the `expm1` and `log1p` functions which happen to be well-standardized function for floating point computation, although I didn't know them before

Proposed formula:

$$ S_N = \frac{-\text{expm1}(N .\text{log1p}(-\varepsilon))}{\varepsilon}$$

which is parametrized by $\varepsilon$ such that $r = 1-\varepsilon$. This change of variable avoids the floating point cancellation error due to computing the difference of numbers close to 1 (i.e. $r$ and $r^n$ in the classical formula).

### Derivation

Starting from

$$S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n = \frac{1-r^N}{1-r},$$

let's replace $r$ by $1-\varepsilon$:

$$S_N = \frac{1-(1-\varepsilon)^N}{\varepsilon}.$$

Now the power is replaced by its definition using the [exponential and logarithm functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms) (i.e. $a^x = \exp(x\log(a))$):

$$S_N = \frac{1-\exp(N \log(1-\varepsilon))}{\varepsilon}$$

The final formula is obtained by identifying the `expm1` and `log1p` functions which are numerically accurate implementations of $x \mapsto \exp(x) -1$ and $x \mapsto \log(1+x)$ respectively.
Both are available in most numerical languages or math libraries (e.g. in Python [`math.expm1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.expm1) and [`math.log1p`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log1p) or in `numpy`).

### Numerical example

Notes: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/pierre-haessig/42972f91dae1edd34f2df86462f6280a) for the complete Python script which generates these results. Computations are done with the standard `float` type of Python 3.8, i.e. a `double` in C  (64 bits on a classical PC).

Here is a test with $N=100$ and a wide range of $\varepsilon$ values, from small ($\varepsilon=0.1$, i.e. $r=0.9$) to extremely small ($\varepsilon=10^{-19}$). First column is the definition of $S_N$ as a partial sum. Second column is the proposed formula. Third column is the classical formula.

```
         Definition with sum   Formula with expm1    Classical formula
ε=1e-01    9.999734386011122    9.999734386011124    9.999734386011127
ε=1e-03   95.207852886290979   95.207852886290951   95.207852886290993
ε=1e-05   99.950516166079737   99.950516166079552   99.950516166080433
ε=1e-07   99.999505001617251   99.999505001616996   99.999505001513100
ε=1e-09   99.999995050000322   99.999995050000180   99.999995003996247
ε=1e-11   99.999999950499969   99.999999950499998  100.000000000000000
ε=1e-13   99.999999999504794   99.999999999504993  100.000000000000000
ε=1e-15   99.999999999995040   99.999999999995055  100.000000000000000
ε=1e-17  100.000000000000000   99.999999999999943      zero div. error
ε=1e-19  100.000000000000000  100.000000000000000      zero div. error
```

Comments about the classical formula (3rd column):

- Contrary to what I thought when I asked the question, the cancellation error in the classical formula doesn't have such a strong effect. Its output is very close to the others for $\varepsilon$ down to $10^{-9}$
- For $\varepsilon = 10^{-11} ... 10^{-15}$, the classical formula gives a result equal to $N$. This is less precise that the true answer, but is reasonable (since $S_N\to N$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$)
- For $\varepsilon$ below $10^{-17}$, the 64 bits floating point arithmetic gives $r=1$ so that we get a *"division by zero" error*. This error could be avoided by replacing $1-r$ by $\varepsilon$ at the denominator, but this would not solve the problem because the numerator is still 0.

Comments about the proposed formula (with `expm1`) versus definition (using a sum):

- Both give comparable results down to very small $\varepsilon=10^{-15}$
- The proposed formula avoids the rounding $S_N=N$ for even smaller value $\varepsilon=10^{-17}$. I don't know if that can be useful for somebody!
- I don't know which one is numerically faster. I supposed that the proposed formula is better for large $N$

Remark: I've no extra implementation which gives me a provably accurate implementation of $S_N$ (perhaps using [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)?). However, for small $\varepsilon$, we can use the quadratic Taylor expensation of $(1-\varepsilon$)^N$ which gives

$$S_N(\varepsilon) \approx_0 N(1-\frac{N-1}{2}\varepsilon) $$

This formula proves that the digit pattern `0.99...9505` is correct for small $\varepsilon$.

### Application to Capital Recovery Factor

The same idea can be applied in finance to the so-called [Capital Recovery Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_recovery_factor). Here $i$, the interest rate, plays the role of the potentially small number:

$$ CRF = \frac{i}{1-(1+i)^{-N}} = \frac{i}{-\text{expm1}(-N .\text{log1p}(i))} $$

In the end, I don't know if somebody ever needs computing a CRF with an interest rate $i \leq 10^{-9}$, but, if so, this formula can be useful!